# Powershell - Splitting one log file into multiple by Date

Tags: powershell, logging, split

I have a log file that generates as a mix of dates, I need to segment this one file out into multiple files only containing entries by date.  As an example, one file would be named `1-2-23` and only contain entries for `Jan. 2nd, 2023`. Next file would be `1-3-23` and only contain entries for `Jan. 3rd, 2023`. etc...

I am not sure what route would be the most efficient as they contain 1,000s of entries, however the entries are separated by the last line of the entry being:

```
-----------------------
```

**EXAMPLE OF LOG FILES**

```
entry is HOSTFIT 0
inserted
group is 0
entry is HOSTFIT 0
code entered
chose no
184357 ejected
184400 taken
184404 presented
USD
16X20 
== NOV 09, 2022 COMPNAME ==
184405 taken
 11/09/22 18:43 COMPNAME
 
12345******6789
SEQ 4201
RANDOMTEXT 320.00
FROM ****882
 
COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY
 
 
AVAIL        32456
 
A1234567891011
PROCESS
-----------------------

inserted
group is 1
entry is HOSTFIT 1
ntry is HOSTFIT 1
192153 inserted
group is 1
entry is HOSTFIT 1
code entered
chose receipt
192221 ejected
192222 aken
192226 presented
240 USD
12X20 
192227 taken
 11/09/22 19:22 12274267
 
45678******9101
SEQ 4202
WITH %240.00
FROM

 
COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY
 
 
AVAIL           936.77
 
A1234567891011
US 
-----------------------
```

**ATTEMPTED CODE 1:**

```
get-content  $Log |
select-string -SimpleMatch '-----------------------' |
set-content "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\Archive\Temp\TestAudit.log"
```

**ATTEMPTED CODE 2:**

```
Get-ChildItem $Log -recurse | ForEach-Object { 
    Get-Content $_ | ForEach-Object { 
        $fields = $_.split('-----------------------')
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Field7 = $fields[7]
            Field8 = $fields[8]
            Field10 = $fields[10]
        }
    }
} | Export-CSV "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\Archive\Temp\TestAudit.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Please share your coding attempt at solving this problem

Comment: I didnt post what I had as both attempts were the way wrong direction.  I tried at first with attempting to match the dashes with Select String -SimpleMatch which just pulled all the dashes out into one file.  Than I attempted .split('-------------') which just exported as a CSV with generic headers I had as place holders but did not actually pull any data.   Ill post the full code up top in one moment for reference.

Comment: That's fine that it didn't work, we can help fix it. We just want to see what you've tried so we know how best to help you learn to do it right, rather than just handing you an answer that fixes the problem, but you may not understand and learn from.

Comment: that's fine, at least it demonstrates that you have tried, did your research and couldn't find a solution and are in needing of help. That's much much better than posting a question with what you need and no code to it

Comment: Much appreciated, just hit a temporary roadblock and trying to figure out which route to go down next, really appreciate you all!

Comment: See, now you deserve an upvote :)

Comment: Splitting in `-----` doesn't sound like a bad idea but for that you would need to use `Get-Content -Raw` so it reads the file as a single string instead of an array of strings already split. Im a bit unclear on where should we get the Dates from, are these dates coming in the next line after the `taken` word?

Comment: sometimes its after taken, sometimes its after entered, and im not sure why but the date shows up one of two ways, either formatted as "mm/dd/YY" or as "== Month Date, Year ComputerName == (1/3/23  or ==Jan 03, 2023 ComputerName ==)

Comment: In your example the Month Day, Year entry also includes mm/dd/yy in the same record. Is that not always the case?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician its odd, I really dont know why it generates each entry as one of the two but not both. There will be three entries in a row as mm/dd/YY  than one with Month Date, Year.   Than another 5 as mm/dd/YY followed by two with Month Date, Year.    I thought maybe the first entry with Month Date would be the start of the day but further I started digging that proved not to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would use `Get-Content` with the `-Raw` parameter to get the entire file, and split it on the dashes. Then use RegEx to match either the `mm/dd/yy` or `MMM dd, yyyy` formatted date, and parse that with `[DateTime]::Parse()` method, and group on that date. Then for each group you can append a log for that date if you archive the logs after processing.

```
$InputFiles = Get-ChildItem $Log -recurse
ForEach($File in $InputFiles){
    $Records = (Get-Content $File.FullName -Raw) -split '(?ms)^-+\s*$'|?{$_}
    $Records | Group-Object {[datetime]::Parse(([regex]::Matches($_,'\b\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\b|\b\w{3} \d\d, \d{4}\b')[0]))} | ForEach-Object {
        Add-Content -Path "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\Archive\Temp\$($_.Name.ToString('mm-dd-yyyy')).log" -Value $_.Group
    }
}
```

If you have to run the same logs over and over then that will get you a lot of duplicate data, and you'd need to de-dupe the records, which could be challenging.

Comment: I intend to compare for duplicate, keep unique and once it's started actually logging goal is only to have the new logs daily.  However, when running your suggestions, I get this error "Group-Object : Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:8 char:16
+ ...  $Records | Group-Object {[datetime]::Parse(([regex]::Matches($_,'\b\ ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"

Comment: hm, that works fine with the example that you gave. You might want to run `$Records|?{$_ -match '\b\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\b|\b\w{3} \d\d, \d{4}\b'}|${$Matches[0]}` and look for things that aren't valid dates. Let me know what you find and I'll see what we can do to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution with the direction given by @TheMadTehcnician

```
$InPC = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\Archive\Temp\"
Get-ChildItem -Path $InPC -Filter *.LOG | ForEach-Object -Process {

        $basename= $_.BaseName   
        $m = ( ( Get-Content $_.FullName | Where-Object { $_ | Select-String "-----------------------" -Quiet } | 
        Measure-Object | 
        ForEach-Object { $_.Count } ) -ge 2) 
        $a = 1
        if ($m) {
  Get-Content $_.FullName | ForEach-Object {

    If ($_ -match "-----------------------") {
        $OutputFile = "$InPC\$basename-$a.LOG"
        $a++
    }    
    Add-Content $OutputFile $_
    }
  Remove-Item $_.FullName 
  }
  }
```